# Migrate JIRA project to cloud-based JIRA hosting

Tags: jira

I am trying to migrate my existing JIRA project on my server to JIRA cloud hosting.  I was able to export my existing project in XML format.  However, for some reason, JIRA cloud based hosting does not seem to support importing a project from XML - the only option that I can find for exporting a server based JIRA project.

Can someone please help me with move my existing server-based JIRA project to JIRA cloud hosting?

Thank you,
Eric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import from self hosted JIRA instance to Cloud is a bit more difficult. You can read documentation about process [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/Cloud/Importing+Issues#ImportingIssues-ImportingissuesfromJIRAandotherthird-partyissuetrackers).
The process is like:

1. Export xml data from existing instance (which you already did).
2. Prepare a zip which will contain your xml data and
   {yourJIRAhome}/data folder.
3. Now you need to upload this zip file to
   Cloud webdav service, [here are docs how to do it](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/Cloud/Uploading+Data+via+WebDAV)
4. This will be
   the last step, you need to go to
   `https://{your-cloud-instance}/secure/admin/StudioImportSelect!start.jspa`
   and follow the wizard steps.

Comment: Thank you SO much!  I had posted on Atlassian's message boards and they actually told me this was not possible, but it is, because I just did it, and it was super easy thanks to you!  You rock!!!

Answer (score 0):

JIRA's guide can be found at https://confluence.atlassian.com/plugins/servlet/mobile#ImportingIssues-ImportingissuesfromJIRAandotherthird-partyissuetrackers. If you are having issues, I would suspect a version compatibility issue ... You may need to upgrade your instance before migrating. Atlassian Cloud is generally a little ahead of the current Download version, but Agile is the only place I have found compatibility issues with a minor release.